# Getting the compression ratio

Tags: binary, ratio, compression

> Given a picture of $200x200$ pixels. Without compression, each pixel
>   uses $10$ bits to represent a color.
>
> This image is compressed lossless by giving the colors a new coding.
>   The coding of these colors is as small as possible, and all colors get
>   the same bit length in this coding.
>
> Suppose you know that a picture always consists of a maximum of $four$
>   colors (purple, orange, lightgreen, blue), what is the compression
>   ratio?

I happen to know that answer to this question is $20\%$. But I'm not sure how to get this myself. Can someone explain to me how I can get the compression ratio here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider how many bits you need per pixel after compression (taking into account that each pixel can only have one of four colours), compared to the ten you needed before. That's your answer.

Comment: How would I get the bits needed after the compression? I assume all 4 colors together make 4 bits per pixel.

Comment: If you have four bits per pixel, then each pixel can have a value ranging from `0000` to `1111`. How many different colours would that be? Do you need that many?

Comment: Wups, I meant 1 bit represents 1 color. so 2 bits would do, since 4 colors

Comment: So you've gone from $10$ bits per pixel to $2$ bits per pixel. That's $20\%$ right there. Or like you've done, from in total $40kb$ to $8kb$.

Comment: A quick question if you don't mind. Say if we had $9$ colors then we would need to use $4$ bits. Would that mean that $7$ bits would go unused? Since you can make $16$ colors with $4$ bits, and we use only $9$.

Comment: @Drago With this encryption scheme, yes (except it's not seven _whole bits_ that are unused, but rather seven of the sixteen possible states of your four bits). For a pair of pixels there are $81$ possible combinations, though, so if you encode pixels two by two you only need 7 bits for each pair, so 3.5 bits per pixel.